# Paypal subscription button for wordpress

Tags: paypal

I have a wordpress website. I wish to place PayPal recurring button, but the default Paypal button as the word "subscription" is there a plugin which can do this or do I have to modify with coding?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the label on your button, go to the source of your button to the "input" tag where "type" attribute is image and replace that with this: